# Text engraving effect in glass

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to preview an engraving effect on glass with some text. Check the [preview image](http://tap2search.com/images/preview.jpeg) of what I want for the result.

Here is my code to convert from the [original image](http://tap2search.com/images/original.png).

```
convert -size 1000x1000 xc:none -draw "image Over 0,0 0,0 \'s2.png\'" \
    -draw "font Candice-10-Pitch font-size 70 fill blue \
          text 190,300 \'mr.\'" \
    -draw "font Candice font-size 40 fill blue \
          text 160,380 \'JITENDRA\'" \
    -draw "font Candice-10-Pitch font-size 30 fill blue \
          text 160,430 \'Sept 26, 1990\'" \ output.jpg
```

I have tried using ImageMagick, but it is not working for me.

Note: showing the text color, it may be custom defined or transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here is how to make the text transparent and to add clip art. In ImageMagick, I create separate images for each text string using label:. Then I composite each text over the background. The text is made with semi-transparent color as is the clip art and the compose method is multiply so as to keep the texture of the background image.

Background:

[image]

Clip Art:

[image]

```
convert s2.png \
\( -background none -font Candice -pointsize 70 -fill "rgb(245,222,179,0.5)" label:'mr.' \) \
-geometry +190+300 -compose multiply -composite \
\( -background none -font Candice -pointsize 40 -fill "rgb(245,222,179,0.5)" label:'JITENDRA' \) \
-geometry +110+380 -compose multiply -composite \
\( -background none -font Candice -pointsize 30 -fill "rgb(245,222,179,0.5)" label:'Sept 26, 1990' \) \
-geometry +160+430 -compose multiply -composite \
\( sun.png -alpha set -channel a -evaluate multiply 0.6 +channel -resize 100x100 \) \
-geometry +200+500 -compose multiply -composite \
-alpha off output.jpg
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your ImageMagick code is too complex. I do not have all your fonts, but here is the way I would code it.

Input:

[image]

```
convert s2.png \
-font Candice -pointsize 70 -fill blue -draw "text 190,300 'mr.'" \
-font Candice -pointsize 40 -fill blue -draw "text 110,380 'JITENDRA'" \
-font Candice -pointsize 30 -fill blue -draw "text 160,430 'Sept 26, 1990'" \
-alpha off output.jpg
```

[image]

Note: I have repeated the font and fill color in case you want to change either for each separate line of text.

Comment: I am trying to understand why you keep setting the font and fill colour repeatedly, please? Surely they are settings and they remain set until changed?

Comment: You can set it once. The second and third sets can be removed. I only did that so that if you wanted different fonts and different colors, it could be changed. He had two different fonts in his original command. I only had one on my system and did not bother downloading the other.

Comment: @fmw42 How to make the transparency text and how to add multiple cliparts in between two lines? check the URL (tap2search.com/images/preview.jpeg)